# Spring @Autowired NullPointerException when try to autowire service in view

Tags: spring-mvc, apache-poi, autowired

I have fully annotated Spring MVC web application. When I try to autowire my service in custom view I am getting `NullPointerException` but not if I autowire in a Controller or other Service.

```
    @Service("excelDataService")
    public class MyService implements iMyService{

    @Override
    public List<Object> getFormattedData(){
     ......
     return list;
    }
  }
```

My controller method

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/export", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView exportToExcel() {

 Map<String,Object> map = Dao.getData()

 return new ModelAndView(new ExcelBuilder(), map);
 }
```

My excel view resolver

```
public class ExcelBuilder extends AbstractXlsxView {

@Autowired
iMyService excelDataService; //--> null 

@Override
protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model,
        Workbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    Sheet latePaymentsSheet = workbook.createSheet("Late Payments");
    List<Object> data = excelDataService.getFormattedData(); //-->NPException

}
```

My question is how can I autowire service in my ExcelBuilder to access the data ?

Comment: In controller method why can't you just set the data to map and access it in ExcelBuilder instead of calling service from ExcelBuilder.

Comment: I am looking for a possibility to access service in view itself so that I can get other benefits as well.

Comment: Do you have any ExcelBuilder objects created with new operator ?

Answer (score 1):

Make your `ExcelBuilder` a component so that Spring container can manage its lifecycle.

Try annotating your `ExcelBuilder` with @Component.

```
@Component
public class ExcelBuilder extends AbstractXlsxView {

    @Autowired 
    private iMyService excelDataService;

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: by adding @Component we are registering ExcelBuilder as a bean. How is that going to autowire the service. I tried your suggestion but not working.

Comment: You cannot autowire your services into any class that is not managed by Spring.

Comment: Yes. I agree. But still I am getting NullPointerException even after adding @Component.

Comment: It could possibly be because your Spring container is unable to instantiate the lifecycle of your `ExcelBuilder` class. Check your component scan property in your spring configuration. Also check if your class `ExcelBuilder` is visible to the spring container for its instantiation.

Comment: I have kept the `ExcelBuilder` and my Controller class in same package for testing purpose. Still spring is not able to autowire the service. How to check whether my class is visible to spring app context for instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

**Actually, the real `ExcelBuilder` instance used to create excel is not created by spring IOC**.

It seems it was created by `new`,you can put a break point in default constructor of `ExcelBuilder`, it will be called when you return a `ModelAndView` in `Controller`.

You can put data you need in the `Model` in Controller, then get in the `ExcelBuilder`.